# how to use date() in magento query?

Tags: magento2, orders, sql, query, date

I want to filter some orders based on the date range so in SQL i use this query

```
SELECT  * FROM  `sales_order` WHERE 
    date(created_at) >= '2020-12-02'
    AND (date( created_at) <= '2020-12-16')
```

in magento i use

```
$orders->addFieldToFilter('date(created_at)', ['qteq' => $startDate->format('Y-m-d')]);
$orders->addFieldToFilter('date(created_at)', ['lteq' => $endDate->format('Y-m-d')]);
```

but it does not work and the result is like this instead

`` SELECT * from sales_order where (`DATE(created_at)` >= '2020-12-01') AND (`DATE(created_at)` <= '2020-12-16) ``

Comment: Did you check if there exists orders in this date range? Also, other filters,if any, are working on this order collection or not?

Comment: yes sure there are orders in this date range, the only problem is idk the way to use the date() in SQL in this filter

Comment: I've given a code in answer, try that.

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/328352/82670

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this below code :

```
$orders->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', ['qteq' => $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
$orders->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
```

**OR**

```
$orders->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', ['qteq' => strtotime($endDate->format('Y-m-d'))]);
$orders->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => strtotime($endDate->format('Y-m-d'))]);
```

**Updated :**

```
$startDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime('2020-12-02'));
$endDate = strtotime("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime('2020-12-16'));
$orders->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', ['from' => $startDate, 'to' => $endDate]);
```

Comment: thanks, but it gives me empty result and the query last like this  AND (((`main_table`.created_at = '1607385600')))
    AND (`main_table`.created_at <= 1607472000)

Comment: Try with updated answer.

Comment: it works but, the result is not true, i mean in that date range it have to have 3 orders but this only shows 2 orders, this filter does not get the orders in the $endDate and this is the reason i use date('created_at') since this gives me 3 orders but unfortunately the syntax for date(''created_at) is wrong.

Comment: put the start date as 2020-12-01 and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me:

```
$now = new \DateTime();
$order->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')])
        ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work too, i have tried this way too

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

```
$startDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime('2020-12-02')); // start date
$endDate = strtotime("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime('2020-12-16')); // end date
     
$orders->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$startDate, 'to'=>$endDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function getSalesOrder($yourDate = null)
 {  
    $date3 = str_replace('/', '-', $yourDate);
    $date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date3));
    $date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $date2);
    $tomorrow = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date1 . "+1 days"));
    $db =$this->db1('sales_order');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sales_order WHERE created_at BETWEEN '$date2' AND '$tomorrow'";
    $base = ($db['connection']->fetchAll($sql));
    return count($base);
         
}
```