# I have below sql query, how do I turn this to Magento get data method to retrieve data?

Tags: magento2, collection, query

I have below sql query, how do I turn this to Magento get data method (collection?) to retrieve data (not using ObjectManager)? Please help.

```
public function  getNewCustomer()
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $query = "SELECT entity_id FROM customer_entity WHERE created_at >=  (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY);";
    $result = $connection->fetchAll($query); 
    
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try this**

```
protected $_customerFactory;

public function __construct(
    ....................................
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    ....................................
)
{
    ....................................
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    ....................................
}


public function getNewCustomers()
{
    $customerData = $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection();
    $customerData->addAttributeToSelect("*");

    $currtDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // Y-m-d h:i:s
    $newDate = strtotime('-10 day', strtotime($currtDate));
    $newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newDate);

    $customerData->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' => $newDate]);
    $customerData->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $currtDate]);

    $customerData->load();

    return $customerData;
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: thanks...I did try few times, .but looks like something wrong with the query,

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code  and update based on your requirement to get customer collection

```
class MyClass 
{
    protected $_customer;
    protected $_customerFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    )
    {

        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    }

  

    public function getFilteredCustomerCollection() {
        return $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                ->addAttributeToFilter("created_at", array("geq" => "(NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY)"))
                -load();
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public function  getNewCustomer()
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $query = "SELECT entity_id FROM customer_entity WHERE created_at >=  (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY);";
    $result = $connection->fetchAll($query); 
    
    return $result;
}
```